# How to write jssor in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, jssor

Jssor http://www.jssor.com/

```
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1440px; height: 560px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="/static/img/photography/004.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="/static/img/photography/thumb-004.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="/static/img/photography/009.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="/static/img/photography/thumb-009.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

angularjs:

```
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1440px; height: 560px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div ng-repeat="coverimg in detailpage.meta.cover">
            <img u="image" src="{{detailpage.meta.cover[0].content.url}}" />
            <img u="thumb" src="{{detailpage.meta.cover[0].content.url}}?imageView/1/w/75/h/50" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then the error is
    TypeError: Cannot read property '$Highlight' of undefined
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$TryActivate' of undefined

Comment: I don't know, I just want to make it as angularjs...

Comment: Did you make it work? I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to check are,

1. Ensure file(s) for jssor slider are included in your page.
2. Ensure all image urls are resolved correctly before you call 'jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(...'

Comment: Actually, the problem is the slider moves the DOM inside the container (adding a second div under it) and angular doesn't catch the changes correctly. And for that reason the elements inside the slider end up all messed.

Comment: Can I have the url that the page runs angularjs and jssor slider?